# Selenium Add Additional Capability not working to set browser version (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I need to test my program on different versions of different browsers. To start, I choose `ChromeDriver` with the following code:

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

ChromeOptions Options = new ChromeOptions();
Options.PlatformName = "windows";
Options.AddAdditionalCapability("platform", "WIN10", true);
Options.AddAdditionalCapability("version", "84", true);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Options);
```

When it starts the webdriver, I go to chrome settings and I see that chrome is still `version 87`

How can I start driver with specific version number?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZItA.jpg) is the screenshot of the page shows the version of chrome

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to have the other (older) version of Chrome on your PC, and then add the following ChromeOption:

Options.BinaryLocation = "%PathToOlderGoogleChromeDirectory%/chrome.exe";

This will then specify which version of chrome you want to use, but you will also need to ensure that your ChromeDriver is compatible with the version of Chrome you have chosen to test on.